# Javascript - HTML5 Input Range Slider - Animation Speed

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to get an HTML 5 slider working. I’m trying to get it to change the value of the  variable moveX. Line 52 works but that is for static. Lines 53 and 54 are what I have tried, but it just creates erratic movement. could somebody help me?

Here is a link to the page:http://hyque.com/ani/drawImageBtnFwd.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DrawImage with Buttons</title>
</head>

<body>

<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn">Pause</button><br />
<p>
<strong>Speed</strong>
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" step="1">

</p>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="187" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">

<script>


window.onload = function() {
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://hyque.com/ani/adam.png";  
var xPos = 0;
var moveX = 0;
var scaleSlider = document.getElementById("slider1");

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 120, 182, 0, 0, 120, 182);


//number(scaleSlider);
var el = document.getElementById('startBtn');
el.addEventListener('click', strt, false);

var el2 = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
el2.addEventListener('click', stopIt, false);

function imageXPosition() {


ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 182);  // This clears the canvas

ctx.drawImage(img, xPos, 0, 120, 182, moveX, 0, 120, 182); //Draws the    individual frames


xPos += 120; //adds the width

//moveX += 5;
moveX += scaleSlider.value;
//scaleSlider.onchange = function(e){moveX = e.target.value;}


//This adds 1 to the second frame
if(xPos == 120){
    xPos += 1;
} 
if(xPos > 841){xPos = 0;}   // This resets to 0 after the las frame
if(moveX >= 1200){moveX = 0;}

}
 var intStp; // declared outside the strt() function, because 

function strt(){
clearInterval(intStp); //without this lin the animation will speed up   eachtime you click "Start Button"
intStp = setInterval(imageXPosition, 200);

}
function stopIt(){
    clearInterval(intStp);
}   
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see this line is problematic:
moveX += scaleSlider.value;

scaleSlider.value returns a string.
moveX is also a string.

When the line above is called you are having something like this

"0" += "1" this results is "01"
after it "01" += "2" which results in "012" etc.

Before solving anything else make sure you use parseInt(moveX, 10);

This will allow you to continue.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I will try and work it out. But I declared moveX a number, so the problem must be in scaleSlider, because using "moveX =+ 5;" works, it's only when I add the slider.

Comment: It worked with: moveX += parseInt(scaleSlider.value)

Comment: That was my intention, that you parse both

Comment: Thank you very much